# Triggering events on another login in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am writing a game in php/javascript/jquery.  This game contains a popuplist of other currently logged in users.  When I select a user in the popuplist, I want to trigger an event, like flashing text or div on the **selected user's browser page.**, but have no idea what I can use other than some form of time/polling. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Polling certainly is an option... though a 'realtime' solution would be more instantaneous. You could use something like socket.io or similar although the setup is relatively complex.

I've seen cloud based services used exceptionally well for things like this. One I've seen that's very easy to integrate with is [Pusher](http://pusher.com/).

Answer (score 0):

So you want user A in one location to click user B's name, and you want this to prompt a pop-up in user B's browser? The only way I can see this happening is to add a record to a MySQL table when user A clicks user Bs name. Then for every user (including user B) you'll need to use AJAX to check for new records where `target` value = user B.

If a record is found you could add what is called a toastr notification on user B's screen: http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Toastr notifications are gentle pop-ups that can rack up on a users screen with any type of trigger.

There is a demo here: http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html